# for loop to export data based on variable name

Tags: python, python-camelot

I have a list of variables I am trying to export to excel. However, I am running into an issue when creating the `for` loop. It seems to be using the actual value of the variable name as opposed to the variable name, which makes sense. I am also trying to name the excel file by the name of the variable, which I thought I can achieve with `str(factor)` in the `for` loop.

The variable factors of the form

```
factors= camelot.read_pdf('Name_pdf',flavor='stream',pages='1-2')

factors=[base_rate,territory_factor,tier_factor,protection_class_factors,age_of_home,protective_device_option,law_multi_new_construc,claim_free,new_home,tenure_aoi,prior_insurance_discount,deductible_peril,construction_type,dwelling_rating_limit,territory_adjustment_factor]


for factor in factors:
    factor.export(str(factor)+'.xlsx',f='excel')
```

Appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already know the filenames, you could do something very simple like :

```
factors= camelot.read_pdf('Name_pdf',flavor='stream',pages='1-2')
factor_names=['base_rate','territory_factor','tier_factor'] # etc..

for factor,factor_name in zip(factors,factor_names):
    factor.export(factor_name+'.xlsx',f='excel')
```

Answer (score 1):

`str(factor)` won't give the name of the variable. The name refers to the object, but in general you can't go the other way.

You could try:

```
factor_name = [k for k, v in locals().items() if v is factor and k != "factor"][0]
factor.export(factor_name+'.xlsx',f='excel')
```

Pretty nasty, though. And remember, [an object can have any number of names, or no name at all](http://effbot.org/zone/python-objects.htm#names).